# How to align 3 column 2 row table to be from right to center?

Tags: html, css

So i am working on a part of the website where i have a Meet-The-Team. 
But my containers are not all centered. I have a 6 containers in total in where i have an image and text where they are both centered in the container, but the container is still on the left. Im trying to move the container from the left to the center.

I tried with many codes like `justify-content: center; align-self: center;`
and every other code that can move the container to the center, but nothing.

```css
/* Three columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 22.2%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small 
    screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
}


/* Add some shadows to create a card effect */

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/* Some left and right padding inside the container*/

.container {
  padding: 0 2px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/* Clear floats */

.container::after,
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

The results end like this

[ C1 ] [ C2 ] [ C3 ]   EMPTY SPACE               |-| <- Scrollbar

I would like it to be like this

EMPTY SPACE  [ C1 ] [ C2 ] [ C3 ] EMPTY SPACE |-| <- Scrollbar

Comment: Sorry for misspels, English is not my first language. :)

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) not only css but also html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of things wrong with your css, seems like you tried a lot, the main problem was you tried to center things while they were all floating left, I changed a couple of things used flexbox and removed the useless parts of the css to get the result you wanted + the responsive part.

```css
/* Three columns side by side */
.column {
  width: 22.2%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  align-self: center;
}


/* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small 
    screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


/* Add some shadows to create a card effect */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}


/* Some left and right padding inside the container*/
.container {
  padding: 0 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <p>AAA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <p>BBB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
        <p>CCC</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it the hard way by <style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 50px"> but i think this is way better.